# Why does add_dependencies add a third party lib into my executable project?

Tags: cmake, cmake-gui

I have the following CMake projects:

`testexe`: which depends on shared library `testlib`

`testlib`: shared library which uses a third party DLL, say `test3rd.lib`

After generating the solution, I found that everything was fine except `testexe` requires `test3rd.lib` as well as `testlib`, but my test should only depend on `testlib`.

What is the reason for this extra dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could link `test3rd.lib` as a `PRIVATE` dependency of `testlib`, `PUBLIC` is default.

```
target_link_libraries(testlib PRIVATE test3rd.lib)
```

**Reference**

- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html